# How to remove redundancies using db2?

Tags: database, db2, repeat, redundancy

Is there some function to remove the redundancies from this table?

This is the query

```
db2 => SELECT qwe.workdept, qwe.lastname, weq.projname, ewq.actno FROM employee qwe, project weq INNER JOIN empprojact ewq ON weq.projno=ewq.projno WHERE workdept='A00'ORDER BY 2,3
```

This is the result.

```
 WORKDEPT LASTNAME        PROJNAME                 ACTNO
 -------- --------------- ------------------------ ------
A00      HAAS            ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          70
A00      HAAS            ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          80
A00      HAAS            ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          80
A00      HAAS            ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          70
A00      HAAS            ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          70
A00      HAAS            ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          60
A00      HAAS            ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          60
A00      HAAS            ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          60
A00      HAAS            ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING         180
A00      HAAS            ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING         180
A00      HAAS            ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING         180
A00      HAAS            ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          80
A00      HAAS            ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          80
A00      HAAS            ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          70
A00      HAAS            ADMIN SERVICES               10
A00      HAAS            APPLICATIONS SUPPORT        140
A00      HAAS            APPLICATIONS SUPPORT        160
A00      HAAS            DB/DC SUPPORT               140
A00      HAAS            DB/DC SUPPORT               170
A00      HAAS            GENERAL ADMIN SYSTEMS        10
A00      HAAS            OPERATION                    10
A00      HAAS            OPERATION                   130
A00      HAAS            OPERATION                   130
A00      HAAS            OPERATION                   130
A00      HAAS            OPERATION                   130
A00      HAAS            OPERATION SUPPORT            10
A00      HAAS            PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          60
A00      HAAS            PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          80
A00      HAAS            PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          70
A00      HAAS            PAYROLL PROGRAMMING         180
A00      HAAS            PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          80
A00      HAAS            PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          70
A00      HAAS            PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          60
A00      HAAS            PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        60
A00      HAAS            PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING       180
A00      HAAS            PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        80
A00      HAAS            PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        80
A00      HAAS            PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        70
A00      HAAS            PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        70
A00      HAAS            PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        70
A00      HAAS            PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        60
A00      HAAS            PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        60
A00      HAAS            QUERY SERVICES               10
A00      HAAS            QUERY SERVICES               90
A00      HAAS            QUERY SERVICES              100
A00      HAAS            QUERY SERVICES               90
A00      HAAS            SCP SYSTEMS SUPPORT         140
A00      HAAS            SCP SYSTEMS SUPPORT         150
A00      HAAS            SYSTEMS SUPPORT              10
A00      HAAS            SYSTEMS SUPPORT              10
A00      HAAS            USER EDUCATION               10
A00      HAAS            USER EDUCATION              110
A00      HAAS            USER EDUCATION              110
A00      HAAS            USER EDUCATION              100
A00      HAAS            USER EDUCATION              100
A00      HAAS            W L PROD CONT PROGS          60
A00      HAAS            W L PROD CONT PROGS         180
A00      HAAS            W L PROD CONT PROGS          80
A00      HAAS            W L PROD CONT PROGS          70
A00      HAAS            W L PROD CONT PROGS          80
A00      HAAS            W L PROGRAM DESIGN           50
A00      HAAS            W L PROGRAM DESIGN           40
A00      HAAS            W L PROGRAM DESIGN           60
A00      HAAS            W L PROGRAMMING              10
A00      HAAS            W L ROBOT DESIGN             60
A00      HAAS            W L ROBOT DESIGN             80
A00      HAAS            W L ROBOT DESIGN             70
A00      HAAS            W L ROBOT DESIGN             70
A00      HAAS            W L ROBOT DESIGN             60
A00      HAAS            W L ROBOT DESIGN            180
A00      HAAS            WELD LINE AUTOMATION         10
A00      HAAS            WELD LINE AUTOMATION         20
A00      HAAS            WELD LINE PLANNING           30
A00      HEMMINGER       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          70
A00      HEMMINGER       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          80
A00      HEMMINGER       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          80
A00      HEMMINGER       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          70
A00      HEMMINGER       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          70
A00      HEMMINGER       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          60
A00      HEMMINGER       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          60
A00      HEMMINGER       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          60
A00      HEMMINGER       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING         180
A00      HEMMINGER       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING         180
A00      HEMMINGER       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING         180
A00      HEMMINGER       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          80
A00      HEMMINGER       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          80
A00      HEMMINGER       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          70
A00      HEMMINGER       ADMIN SERVICES               10
A00      HEMMINGER       APPLICATIONS SUPPORT        140
A00      HEMMINGER       APPLICATIONS SUPPORT        160
A00      HEMMINGER       DB/DC SUPPORT               140
A00      HEMMINGER       DB/DC SUPPORT               170
A00      HEMMINGER       GENERAL ADMIN SYSTEMS        10
A00      HEMMINGER       OPERATION                    10
A00      HEMMINGER       OPERATION                   130
A00      HEMMINGER       OPERATION                   130
A00      HEMMINGER       OPERATION                   130
A00      HEMMINGER       OPERATION                   130
A00      HEMMINGER       OPERATION SUPPORT            10
A00      HEMMINGER       PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          60
A00      HEMMINGER       PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          80
A00      HEMMINGER       PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          70
A00      HEMMINGER       PAYROLL PROGRAMMING         180
A00      HEMMINGER       PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          80
A00      HEMMINGER       PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          70
A00      HEMMINGER       PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          60
A00      HEMMINGER       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        60
A00      HEMMINGER       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING       180
A00      HEMMINGER       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        80
A00      HEMMINGER       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        80
A00      HEMMINGER       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        70
A00      HEMMINGER       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        70
A00      HEMMINGER       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        70
A00      HEMMINGER       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        60
A00      HEMMINGER       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        60
A00      HEMMINGER       QUERY SERVICES               10
A00      HEMMINGER       QUERY SERVICES               90
A00      HEMMINGER       QUERY SERVICES              100
A00      HEMMINGER       QUERY SERVICES               90
A00      HEMMINGER       SCP SYSTEMS SUPPORT         140
A00      HEMMINGER       SCP SYSTEMS SUPPORT         150
A00      HEMMINGER       SYSTEMS SUPPORT              10
A00      HEMMINGER       SYSTEMS SUPPORT              10
A00      HEMMINGER       USER EDUCATION               10
A00      HEMMINGER       USER EDUCATION              110
A00      HEMMINGER       USER EDUCATION              110
A00      HEMMINGER       USER EDUCATION              100
A00      HEMMINGER       USER EDUCATION              100
A00      HEMMINGER       W L PROD CONT PROGS          60
A00      HEMMINGER       W L PROD CONT PROGS         180
A00      HEMMINGER       W L PROD CONT PROGS          80
A00      HEMMINGER       W L PROD CONT PROGS          70
A00      HEMMINGER       W L PROD CONT PROGS          80
A00      HEMMINGER       W L PROGRAM DESIGN           50
A00      HEMMINGER       W L PROGRAM DESIGN           40
A00      HEMMINGER       W L PROGRAM DESIGN           60
A00      HEMMINGER       W L PROGRAMMING              10
A00      HEMMINGER       W L ROBOT DESIGN             60
A00      HEMMINGER       W L ROBOT DESIGN             80
A00      HEMMINGER       W L ROBOT DESIGN             70
A00      HEMMINGER       W L ROBOT DESIGN             70
A00      HEMMINGER       W L ROBOT DESIGN             60
A00      HEMMINGER       W L ROBOT DESIGN            180
A00      HEMMINGER       WELD LINE AUTOMATION         10
A00      HEMMINGER       WELD LINE AUTOMATION         20
A00      HEMMINGER       WELD LINE PLANNING           30
A00      LUCCHESSI       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          70
A00      LUCCHESSI       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          80
A00      LUCCHESSI       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          80
A00      LUCCHESSI       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          70
A00      LUCCHESSI       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          70
A00      LUCCHESSI       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          60
A00      LUCCHESSI       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          60
A00      LUCCHESSI       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          60
A00      LUCCHESSI       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING         180
A00      LUCCHESSI       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING         180
A00      LUCCHESSI       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING         180
A00      LUCCHESSI       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          80
A00      LUCCHESSI       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          80
A00      LUCCHESSI       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          70
A00      LUCCHESSI       ADMIN SERVICES               10
A00      LUCCHESSI       APPLICATIONS SUPPORT        140
A00      LUCCHESSI       APPLICATIONS SUPPORT        160
A00      LUCCHESSI       DB/DC SUPPORT               140
A00      LUCCHESSI       DB/DC SUPPORT               170
A00      LUCCHESSI       GENERAL ADMIN SYSTEMS        10
A00      LUCCHESSI       OPERATION                    10
A00      LUCCHESSI       OPERATION                   130
A00      LUCCHESSI       OPERATION                   130
A00      LUCCHESSI       OPERATION                   130
A00      LUCCHESSI       OPERATION                   130
A00      LUCCHESSI       OPERATION SUPPORT            10
A00      LUCCHESSI       PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          60
A00      LUCCHESSI       PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          80
A00      LUCCHESSI       PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          70
A00      LUCCHESSI       PAYROLL PROGRAMMING         180
A00      LUCCHESSI       PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          80
A00      LUCCHESSI       PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          70
A00      LUCCHESSI       PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          60
A00      LUCCHESSI       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        60
A00      LUCCHESSI       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING       180
A00      LUCCHESSI       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        80
A00      LUCCHESSI       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        80
A00      LUCCHESSI       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        70
A00      LUCCHESSI       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        70
A00      LUCCHESSI       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        70
A00      LUCCHESSI       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        60
A00      LUCCHESSI       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        60
A00      LUCCHESSI       QUERY SERVICES               10
A00      LUCCHESSI       QUERY SERVICES               90
A00      LUCCHESSI       QUERY SERVICES              100
A00      LUCCHESSI       QUERY SERVICES               90
A00      LUCCHESSI       SCP SYSTEMS SUPPORT         140
A00      LUCCHESSI       SCP SYSTEMS SUPPORT         150
A00      LUCCHESSI       SYSTEMS SUPPORT              10
A00      LUCCHESSI       SYSTEMS SUPPORT              10
A00      LUCCHESSI       USER EDUCATION               10
A00      LUCCHESSI       USER EDUCATION              110
A00      LUCCHESSI       USER EDUCATION              110
A00      LUCCHESSI       USER EDUCATION              100
A00      LUCCHESSI       USER EDUCATION              100
A00      LUCCHESSI       W L PROD CONT PROGS          60
A00      LUCCHESSI       W L PROD CONT PROGS         180
A00      LUCCHESSI       W L PROD CONT PROGS          80
A00      LUCCHESSI       W L PROD CONT PROGS          70
A00      LUCCHESSI       W L PROD CONT PROGS          80
A00      LUCCHESSI       W L PROGRAM DESIGN           50
A00      LUCCHESSI       W L PROGRAM DESIGN           40
A00      LUCCHESSI       W L PROGRAM DESIGN           60
A00      LUCCHESSI       W L PROGRAMMING              10
A00      LUCCHESSI       W L ROBOT DESIGN             60
A00      LUCCHESSI       W L ROBOT DESIGN             80
A00      LUCCHESSI       W L ROBOT DESIGN             70
A00      LUCCHESSI       W L ROBOT DESIGN             70
A00      LUCCHESSI       W L ROBOT DESIGN             60
A00      LUCCHESSI       W L ROBOT DESIGN            180
A00      LUCCHESSI       WELD LINE AUTOMATION         10
A00      LUCCHESSI       WELD LINE AUTOMATION         20
A00      LUCCHESSI       WELD LINE PLANNING           30
A00      O'CONNELL       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          70
A00      O'CONNELL       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          80
A00      O'CONNELL       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          80
A00      O'CONNELL       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          70
A00      O'CONNELL       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          70
A00      O'CONNELL       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          60
A00      O'CONNELL       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          60
A00      O'CONNELL       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          60
A00      O'CONNELL       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING         180
A00      O'CONNELL       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING         180
A00      O'CONNELL       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING         180
A00      O'CONNELL       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          80
A00      O'CONNELL       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          80
A00      O'CONNELL       ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          70
A00      O'CONNELL       ADMIN SERVICES               10
A00      O'CONNELL       APPLICATIONS SUPPORT        140
A00      O'CONNELL       APPLICATIONS SUPPORT        160
A00      O'CONNELL       DB/DC SUPPORT               140
A00      O'CONNELL       DB/DC SUPPORT               170
A00      O'CONNELL       GENERAL ADMIN SYSTEMS        10
A00      O'CONNELL       OPERATION                    10
A00      O'CONNELL       OPERATION                   130
A00      O'CONNELL       OPERATION                   130
A00      O'CONNELL       OPERATION                   130
A00      O'CONNELL       OPERATION                   130
A00      O'CONNELL       OPERATION SUPPORT            10
A00      O'CONNELL       PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          60
A00      O'CONNELL       PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          80
A00      O'CONNELL       PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          70
A00      O'CONNELL       PAYROLL PROGRAMMING         180
A00      O'CONNELL       PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          80
A00      O'CONNELL       PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          70
A00      O'CONNELL       PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          60
A00      O'CONNELL       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        60
A00      O'CONNELL       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING       180
A00      O'CONNELL       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        80
A00      O'CONNELL       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        80
A00      O'CONNELL       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        70
A00      O'CONNELL       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        70
A00      O'CONNELL       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        70
A00      O'CONNELL       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        60
A00      O'CONNELL       PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        60
A00      O'CONNELL       QUERY SERVICES               10
A00      O'CONNELL       QUERY SERVICES               90
A00      O'CONNELL       QUERY SERVICES              100
A00      O'CONNELL       QUERY SERVICES               90
A00      O'CONNELL       SCP SYSTEMS SUPPORT         140
A00      O'CONNELL       SCP SYSTEMS SUPPORT         150
A00      O'CONNELL       SYSTEMS SUPPORT              10
A00      O'CONNELL       SYSTEMS SUPPORT              10
A00      O'CONNELL       USER EDUCATION               10
A00      O'CONNELL       USER EDUCATION              110
A00      O'CONNELL       USER EDUCATION              110
A00      O'CONNELL       USER EDUCATION              100
A00      O'CONNELL       USER EDUCATION              100
A00      O'CONNELL       W L PROD CONT PROGS          60
A00      O'CONNELL       W L PROD CONT PROGS         180
A00      O'CONNELL       W L PROD CONT PROGS          80
A00      O'CONNELL       W L PROD CONT PROGS          70
A00      O'CONNELL       W L PROD CONT PROGS          80
A00      O'CONNELL       W L PROGRAM DESIGN           50
A00      O'CONNELL       W L PROGRAM DESIGN           40
A00      O'CONNELL       W L PROGRAM DESIGN           60
A00      O'CONNELL       W L PROGRAMMING              10
A00      O'CONNELL       W L ROBOT DESIGN             60
A00      O'CONNELL       W L ROBOT DESIGN             80
A00      O'CONNELL       W L ROBOT DESIGN             70
A00      O'CONNELL       W L ROBOT DESIGN             70
A00      O'CONNELL       W L ROBOT DESIGN             60
A00      O'CONNELL       W L ROBOT DESIGN            180
A00      O'CONNELL       WELD LINE AUTOMATION         10
A00      O'CONNELL       WELD LINE AUTOMATION         20
A00      O'CONNELL       WELD LINE PLANNING           30
A00      ORLANDO         ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          70
A00      ORLANDO         ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          80
A00      ORLANDO         ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          80
A00      ORLANDO         ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          70
A00      ORLANDO         ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          70
A00      ORLANDO         ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          60
A00      ORLANDO         ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          60
A00      ORLANDO         ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          60
A00      ORLANDO         ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING         180
A00      ORLANDO         ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING         180
A00      ORLANDO         ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING         180
A00      ORLANDO         ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          80
A00      ORLANDO         ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          80
A00      ORLANDO         ACCOUNT PROGRAMMING          70
A00      ORLANDO         ADMIN SERVICES               10
A00      ORLANDO         APPLICATIONS SUPPORT        140
A00      ORLANDO         APPLICATIONS SUPPORT        160
A00      ORLANDO         DB/DC SUPPORT               140
A00      ORLANDO         DB/DC SUPPORT               170
A00      ORLANDO         GENERAL ADMIN SYSTEMS        10
A00      ORLANDO         OPERATION                    10
A00      ORLANDO         OPERATION                   130
A00      ORLANDO         OPERATION                   130
A00      ORLANDO         OPERATION                   130
A00      ORLANDO         OPERATION                   130
A00      ORLANDO         OPERATION SUPPORT            10
A00      ORLANDO         PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          60
A00      ORLANDO         PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          80
A00      ORLANDO         PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          70
A00      ORLANDO         PAYROLL PROGRAMMING         180
A00      ORLANDO         PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          80
A00      ORLANDO         PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          70
A00      ORLANDO         PAYROLL PROGRAMMING          60
A00      ORLANDO         PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        60
A00      ORLANDO         PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING       180
A00      ORLANDO         PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        80
A00      ORLANDO         PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        80
A00      ORLANDO         PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        70
A00      ORLANDO         PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        70
A00      ORLANDO         PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        70
A00      ORLANDO         PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        60
A00      ORLANDO         PERSONNEL PROGRAMMING        60
A00      ORLANDO         QUERY SERVICES               10
A00      ORLANDO         QUERY SERVICES               90
A00      ORLANDO         QUERY SERVICES              100
A00      ORLANDO         QUERY SERVICES               90
A00      ORLANDO         SCP SYSTEMS SUPPORT         140
A00      ORLANDO         SCP SYSTEMS SUPPORT         150
A00      ORLANDO         SYSTEMS SUPPORT              10
A00      ORLANDO         SYSTEMS SUPPORT              10
A00      ORLANDO         USER EDUCATION               10
A00      ORLANDO         USER EDUCATION              110
A00      ORLANDO         USER EDUCATION              110
A00      ORLANDO         USER EDUCATION              100
A00      ORLANDO         USER EDUCATION              100
A00      ORLANDO         W L PROD CONT PROGS          60
A00      ORLANDO         W L PROD CONT PROGS         180
A00      ORLANDO         W L PROD CONT PROGS          80
A00      ORLANDO         W L PROD CONT PROGS          70
A00      ORLANDO         W L PROD CONT PROGS          80
A00      ORLANDO         W L PROGRAM DESIGN           50
A00      ORLANDO         W L PROGRAM DESIGN           40
A00      ORLANDO         W L PROGRAM DESIGN           60
A00      ORLANDO         W L PROGRAMMING              10
A00      ORLANDO         W L ROBOT DESIGN             60
A00      ORLANDO         W L ROBOT DESIGN             80
A00      ORLANDO         W L ROBOT DESIGN             70
A00      ORLANDO         W L ROBOT DESIGN             70
A00      ORLANDO         W L ROBOT DESIGN             60
A00      ORLANDO         W L ROBOT DESIGN            180
A00      ORLANDO         WELD LINE AUTOMATION         10
A00      ORLANDO         WELD LINE AUTOMATION         20
A00      ORLANDO         WELD LINE PLANNING           30

365 record(s) selected.
```

Is it possible to remove the repeating information from col 3?
BTW, I'm using db2 and Sample database.

PS: 3rd time posting here and currently new in using db2.

Comment: You're mixing explicit joins (`INNER JOIN ... ON`) with an implicit join (comma-separated `FROM`) _and you don't have a condition for the implicit join_.  You're getting a Cartesian product; you're lucky you don't have **more** rows.  Always use explicit joins, and put as many conditions as possible/reasonable in the `ON` clause.  Fix that, then see if you still get duplicates.  In any case, it's impossible for us to see where the duplicates are actually coming from, other than the usual "you forgot a condition somewhere".

Comment: What do you mean by `from col 3`? Please show a sample of what you expect output to look like.